# How do bitstring oracles work in quantum circuits?

Tags: deutsch-jozsa-algorithm, oracles

In most diagrams of oracles for basic algorithms such as Deutsch-Jozsa (e.g., https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/deutsch-jozsa.html) the inputs are bitstrings $x$ and $y$, and outputs are bitstrings $x$ and $y \oplus f(x)$.

When used in a quantum circuit, the oracle is given quantum states, $|x\rangle$ and $|y \rangle$, where $|x\rangle$ is often in superposition, and $|y\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the oracle. The output of the oracle can be seen as the result of phase kickback ([https://people.vcu.edu/~sgharibian/courses/CMSC491/notes/Lecture%206%20-%20Deutsch's%20algorithm.pdf](https://people.vcu.edu/%7Esgharibian/courses/CMSC491/notes/Lecture%206%20-%20Deutsch%27s%20algorithm.pdf)):

$$
U_f|x\rangle|-\rangle = (-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle|-\rangle
$$

I have a question:

The oracle's inputs and outputs are shown as bitstrings, not states. Where, and how, are the circuit's input states $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ turned into bitstrings $x$ and $y$ before the oracle, and then back into states after? Or should the diagram be showing a quantum version of the oracle, and the input/output labels should be states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input states $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ are vectors, but you can also interpret them as bitstrings using the computational basis $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$. For example, if $x=010$, then we can encode that bitstring as $|x\rangle=|0\rangle|1\rangle|0\rangle=|010\rangle$. In the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm, the input state $|x\rangle$ for the unitary $U_f$ is actually the superposition of all $2^n$ bitstring states: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}}}\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}|x\rangle$. Starting from the all zeros state ${|0\rangle}^{\otimes n}$, this state can be obtained by applying a Hadamard gate $H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ to each of the $n$ qubits.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me. But there's still a piece missing. As drawn, the output of the oracle is a bitstring. Even if we interpret that as a tensor product of the basis states, bitstrings don't have a sign (as far as I know). But the sign change on some states is essential to an algorithm like D-J. As drawn, there's no explicit way to attach that $-1$ to some output bitstrings, and thus some states. Is this diagram, as drawn, not therefore incomplete?

Comment: @Eleeza Isn't the result of D-J, $|0\rangle ^{\otimes n} = "0 \cdots 0"$ if $f(x)$ is constant or something else if $f(x)$ is balanced. I don't see where a negative sign is required here. Mathematically, there can be a negative sign in the superposition when representing it in the basis ${|0\rangle, |1\rangle}$, but as you said, the output needs to be one of the basis states.

Comment: Thanks! My question is not about the algorithm, but that the diagram and algorithm don't match. The diagram shows the upper qubits going into $H$ gates, then an oracle which (as drawn) outputs the same bitstring $x$ it receives as input, then more $H$ gates. The oracle (as drawn) is thus an identity on the upper register, the two $H$ sets invert one another, and so the upper register (again, as drawn) isn't changed in any way. But we know that it does change - that's the whole point, and the role of the $-1$ in my original post. So this standard circuit diagram must be missing something, no?

Comment: @Eleeza I think you can find the answer to your question in [this](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/deutsch-jozsa.html#1.4-Why-Does-This-Work?--) paragraph. They explain this intuitively in the second part. As you said if the function is constant nothing happens with the oracle, so you end with $|0\rangle ^{\otimes n}$. However as you said, with a balanced function, we end, before the last $H$ gates, with $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ which if you do the calculation is orthogonal to $|0\rangle ^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: As the $H$ gate is unitary, it does not affect the scalar product and thus after applying it, we will still have a gate that is orthogonal to $|0\rangle ^{\otimes n}$ and thus will never measure $|0\rangle ^{\otimes n}$ and have a different bit-string.

Comment: @BrokenDuck You've drawn the input to the last gate as a state composed of $1$ and $-1$ values. But both outputs of the oracle are bitstrings, which (as far as I know) don't have a sign. In your example, if we take $n=3$, then state $|010\rangle$ has the value $-1$. The oracle can output the bitstring $010$, but not $-010$, so where, **in the diagram, not the algorithm**, does the $-1$ come from?